# MVC ActionLink how to specify text, actionname, controller and htmlattributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have been trying to do an actionlink like:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Invoice", new { id = "homelink" })</li>
```

So what I have is linkText, an actionname, a controller name and an id for the link.

However there is no signature that matches this. The closest one has routevalues between the controller name and the htmlattributes. I don't have any routevalues I need to put in there though.

Can someone please tell me how to best get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set route values to `null` and your're good to go!

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Invoice", null, new { id = "homelink" })
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

Assuming i understand what you are asking for, there is an overload for that

#### Sample

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", 
                  null, new { id="homelink" })
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx)